# Java 8 functions and classes

Tags: java, function, lambda, java-8

In Java 8, can a function reside in a package without defining a class?

It seems like there is no need for a class when you have a function.

I am familiar with Java but new to functional programming. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sort of, but functions to not stand alone as first class citizens like in a functional programming language.

In Java 8 you can add a method to an Interface, or an Enum.

```
public interface Loggable {

    default Logger logger() {
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    }
}


public enum Level {
    HIGH  (3),
    MEDIUM(2),
    LOW   (1)

    private final int levelCode;

    Level(int levelCode) {
        this.levelCode = levelCode;
    }

    public int getLevelCode() {
        return this.levelCode;
    }
}
```

There is also a special annotation in Java 8 called the [FunctionalInterface](http://java.dzone.com/articles/introduction-functional-1) that can be used to create a function interface that can be implemented in line without being a member of a Class.

If you really want to do functional programming in Java because you want to avoid maintaining state in lower order functions you can always make those functions static and then treat the Class as a package. This way you don't have to do any object creation.

Comment: @user5073576 - Since you are new here I will let you know that you should upvote any/all of the answers to your question you've found useful. If you believe one of the answers has solved your question best you can accept it as correct so that the community will know your problem is solved.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown: the OP argues that there's no need for a class when you have a function, but there's also no need for an interface, or an enum (which is essentially a class anyway). And you also can't declare a lambda without a surrounding method (or a class, ...) to put it in. I mean, the point is that Java doesn't allow free-floating functions in the same way that for example C++ does.

Comment: The question is whether or not functions can be defined without a class, not if they are allowed to be free form.

Comment: jeremy, I tried to upvote, but I have to earn more points first.

Answer (score 3):

No, a function in Java 8 is represented by a functional interface. A functional interface can be implemented by a class that implements that interface, by a lambda expression that implements the single method of that interface or by a method reference. In all of these cases, the implementation of the "function" resides in some class.

Comment: This answer discounts Enums, which are a way to define a function without a class.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown Enums are also classes.

Answer (score 1):

You may declare a `final class` which cannot be instantiated (make `private` constructor) and put your functions there as static methods of this class. You can think of this class as a "namespace" for your functions. To use them without specifying the class name you can import this class statically:

```
import static com.example.mypackage.MyUtilityClass.*;
```

Such approach is widely used in many Java libraries and in JDK (for example, `java.lang.Math` class).

Answer (score 0):

No. Java doesn't have functions, only methods that are part of a class.

Comment: "only methods that are part of a class" Java has methods that are not part of a Class.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown: okay, could you back that up with an example?